# GetKeyboardLayout(0) return same result

Tags: linux, wine, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to get the layout used in the application by calling

`HKL lt = GetKeyboardLayout (0);`

Вut I get the same result - lt = 04190419x, regardless of which layout is currently being used. The program is written in Delphi under Windows, GUI is used, runs on OS AstraLinux using wine-3.0. The AstraLinux system has 2 layouts - English[US] and Russian. When running this application under Windows, the layout used is determined correctly - GetKeyboardLayout (0) = 04090409x on the English[US] layout and GetKeyboardLayout (0) = 04190419x on the Russian layout. But when working under AstraLinux, GetKeyboardLayout (0) always returns 04190419x, regardless of the layout used - English[US] or Russian.

Comment: This sounds like a wine question primarily. Personally I think you are more likely to generate interest if you provide a simple C or C++ [mcve] to demonstrate the issue and stop people questioning whether or not this is a Delphi related issue. I think knowing the version of wine under which the program runs would also be useful.

Comment: I use wine-3.0. I also think that the problem is in the wine. I put the wine tag in the first place, but when I post a question, the linux tag comes in front.